# jquery 1 line, how to add an extra value to the width to animate

Tags: jquery, width

```
var gunboxwidth = ($('h2 span').widest().width() + "px" + 30 + "px")
```

.widest() grabs the wides span inside of an h2, the problem i'm having is that it works fine when i DO NOT have

`+ 30 + 'px'`

why is that? is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var gunboxwidth = ($('h2 span').widest().width() + 30 + "px");
```

This adds 30 to the numerical value returned from the `width` function, then converts it to a string and adds the 'px' suffix.

For example, if the width of the span is '20', the JQuery `width` function will return the number 20 - not a string like '20px'. So the above code adds 30 to that and results in the string '50px'. What you have would result in a string value of:

```
'20px30px'
```

...since when you add strings together, the second is just appended to the first.

```
20 + 'px' = '20px'
'20px' + 30 = '20px30'
'20px30' + 'px' = '20px30px'
```

---

You're probably better off using:

```
var gunboxwidth = ($('h2 span').widest().width() + 30);
```

...to keep it numeric, and then using that to e.g. set the width of another item using JQuery's `width` function again, like:

```
$('.selector').width(gunboxwidth);
```